# Simplex Method gives multiple, unbounded solutions but Graphical Method gives unique soution

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, simplex-method

I'm taking an undergraduate course on Linear Programming and we were asked to solve the following problem using the Simplex Method:$$\max:~Z=3x+2y\\\text{subject to}\begin{cases}x+y\le20\\0\le x\le15\\x+3y\le45\\-3x+5y\le60\\y\text{ unrestricted in sign}\end{cases}$$The standard form of the LPP is$$\max:~Z=3x+2m-2n\\\text{subject to}\begin{cases}x+m-n+a=20\\x+b=15\\x+3m-3n+c=45\\-3x+5m-5n+d=60\\x,m,n,a,b,c,d\ge0\end{cases}$$where $y=m-n$. The optimal Simplex tableau was obtained$$\begin{matrix}&&3&2&-2&0&0&0&0\\&\text{Basis}&x&m&n&a&b&c&d&\text{RHS}\\2&m&0&1&-1&1&0&0&-1&5\\0&b&0&0&0&-3&1&0&2&15\\0&c&0&0&0&-5&0&1&8&80\\3&x&1&0&0&0&0&0&1&15\\&\text{Deviations}&0&0&\color{red}0&-2&0&0&-1&Z=55\end{matrix}$$Since all deviations are negative, the stopping criteria is fulfilled. But the deviation corresponding to non-basic $n$ is $0$, so this must be a case of multiple optimal solutions. With $n$ as the entering variable the minimum ratio test fails, which means this is also a case of unbounded solutions.

On solving the same question using Graphical method, I got a unique solution $Z=55$ at $(15,5)$. What is the problem in the Simplex Method?

[image: Graphical Method]

Comment: Any solution for $y$ yields infinitely many solutions for $m, n$.

Comment: @RobertShore Okay, but how do you infer that the optimal solution for $y$ is unique? In other words how do we know $m-n$ will be fixed for all optimal solutions? What if some other optimal solution had $y=7$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this problem, the non-uniqueness in the simplex method comes from the substitution $y = m-n$: a single value of $y$ can be expressed as $m-n$ in many ways.

To see that this is the only reason for non-uniqueness, we can parametrize the solutions found by the simplex method and find all the possible solutions.

The bottom row of your tableau actually corresponds to the equation $z = 55 - 2a - d$. So we know that we obtain the optimal value of $z=55$ exactly when $a=d=0$.

To make this substitution, we delete the $a$ and $d$ columns from the tableau, and get the system of equations
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ m \\ n \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 15 \\ 80 \\ 15\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
which tells us that the optimal solutions are those feasible solutions which have $m-n=5$, $b = 15$, $c = 80$, and $x=15$ (and $a=d=0$).

Since $y = m-n=5$ is fixed, the simplex method confirms that actually there's only one solution $(x,y) = (15,5)$ after we undo this substitution and return to the original formulation of the LP.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The simplex method will produce the correct answer:
$$\max:~Z=3x+2y\\\text{subject to}\begin{cases}x+y\le20\\0\le x\le15\\x+3y\le45\\-3x+5y\le60\\y\text{ unrestricted in sign}\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}x+y+s_1=20\\x+s_2=15\\x+3y+s_3=45\\-3x+5y+s_4=60\\y\text{ unrestricted in sign}\end{cases}\\
\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
x&y&s_1&s_2&s_3&s_4&C\\
\hline
1&1&1&0&0&0&20&s_1\\
\boxed1&0&0&1&0&0&15&s_2\\
1&3&0&0&1&0&45&s_3\\
-3&5&0&0&0&1&60&s_4\\
\hline
-3&-2&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{array} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
x&y&s_1&s_2&s_3&s_4&C\\
\hline
0&\boxed1&1&-1&0&0&5&s_1\\
1&0&0&1&0&0&15&x\\
0&3&0&-1&1&0&30&s_3\\
0&5&0&3&0&1&105&s_4\\
\hline
0&-2&0&3&0&0&45\\
\end{array} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
x&y&s_1&s_2&s_3&s_4&C\\
\hline
0&1&1&-1&0&0&\color{red}5&y\\
1&0&0&1&0&0&\color{red}{15}&x\\
0&0&-3&2&1&0&15&s_3\\
0&0&-5&8&0&1&80&s_4\\
\hline
0&0&2&1&0&0&\color{red}{55}\\
\end{array}$$
Thus: $z(15,5)=55$ is the maximum.

Comment: Doesn't the application of the Simplex Method entail that all variables are non-negative?

Comment: Conventionally, yes. In theory, you can still kind of make the simplex method work when $y$ is unrestricted. To do this, begin by bringing $y$ into the basis (even if this decreases $z$). Once $y$ is basic, just make sure it never leaves the basis, even if it becomes negative. It's a bit tricky to think through and isn't really worth it, which is why we replace $y$ by $m-n$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, you are right, I considered $y\ge 0$, because if $y\le 0$, the pivot column will still be $x$ column, while the $y$ coefficient in the last row will be $+2$, hence we get the optimal solution $z(15,0)=45$ right away, which is less than the case $y\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve used a solver and get a slightly different final tableau. My initial tableau is

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline x_1&y_1&y_2&s_1&s_2&s_3&s_4&RHS \\ \hline 1&1&-1&1&0&0&0&20 \\ \hline 1&0&0&0&1&0&0&15 \\ \hline 1&3&-3&0&0&1&0&45 \\ \hline -3&5&-5&0&0&0&1&60 \\ \hline -3&-2&2&0&0&0&0&0\\ \hline\end{array}$$

The last line is the objective function. According to the simplex alogrithm we need $y=y_1-y_2$ since $y$ is not bounded. Here $y_1,y_2\geq 0$ And $s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4\geq 0$ are the slack variables. The corresponding final tableau is

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline x_1&y_1&y_2&s_1&s_2&s_3&s_4&RHS \\ \hline 0&1&\color{red}{-1}&1&-1&0&0&5 \\ \hline 1&0&0&0&1&0&0&15 \\ \hline 0&0&0&-3&2&1&0&15 \\ \hline 0&0&0&-5&8&0&1&80 \\ \hline 0&0&0&2&1&0&0&55\\ \hline \end{array}$$

Our final tableaus are equal except that the columns 5 and 7 are swapped. But the conclusion is the same. You can  make a pivot operation only if the corresponding value of $a_{ij}$ is greater than $0$. But here we have $a_{13}=\color{red}{-1}$. So the simplex algorithm stops here. The optimal solution is $(x^*,y^*,s_1^*,s_2^*,s_3^*,s_4^*)=(15,5,0,0,15,80)$ since all coefficients of the objective function are greater or equal than $0$.

**Remark**

You start with values with reversed signs at  the row for the objective function. This is valid as well. That means that the  row for the objective function at the final tableau is  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline 0&0&0&-2&-1&0&0&-55\\ \hline \end{array}\Rightarrow z^*=55$

The criteria for  stopping the simplex algorithm is that the coefficients of the objective function must be non-positive. This is the case here.

**Remark 2**

If you consider the inequalities the solution space looks like the yellow one. The red arrows indicates that the solution space goes further.

[image]

Comment: Yes, one optimal solution is at $(15,5)$ since all deviations are non-positive, but deviation of non-basic $y_2$ being $0$ indicates there are multiple solutions. Conventionally to find the other vertex of optimality, I am required to make $y_2$ enter the basis, but here the minimum ratio test fails and the leaving variable can't be figured out, indicating unbounded solution. My question is, how can we be sure that the value of $x$ and $y$ doesn't change in those solutions?

Comment: If you say that $  y=y_1-y_2$ then the simplex algorithm ensures that one of the variables is $0$. I don´t know why you say that $y_2$ should enter the basis. Only one of the two variables enter the basis.

Comment: " *but deviation of non-basic y2 being 0 indicates there are multiple solutions* ": No, this is not true-definitively!

Comment: I am told that when the stopping criterion is fulfilled but the deviation corresponding to any non-basic variable is $0$, there are multiple solutions. To obtain another optimal solution, the aforesaid variable is made to enter the basis. Of course in this case, a solution means the tuple $(x,m,n,a,b,c,d)$. Non-uniqueness of the optimal solution is caused by $y=m-n$ leading to infinitely many pairs $(m,n)$ for the same value of $y$, but how to be certain that the non-uniqueness is caused only due to this and the value of $y$ in all optimal solutions is the same?

Comment: " *Non-uniqueness of the optimal solution is caused by y=m−n* " No, no, no. The simplex algorithm ensures that at least one of the variables is $0$.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Aren't $(x,m,n)=(15,5,0,),(15,6,1)$ both optimal solutions looking at the original system of constraints?

Comment: But the second solution is not part of the simplex algorithm solution. That´s the point. So $x^*15, y^*=5-0=5$ Just trust the simplex algorithm.

Comment: You overlook that $0$ deviation of non-basic variable corresponds to multiple solutions in the simplex method, and failure of the minimum ratio test corresponds to unbounded solutions. This is how one detects whether a system has unique/multiple/unbounded/infeasible solutions in the simplex algorithm.

Comment: *You overlook that 0 deviation of non-basic variable corresponds to multiple solutions in the simplex method* Not if you **cannot make a pivot operation**. Again, trust the simplex algorithm.

Comment: Look at this example:$$\max~z =6x_1–2x_2\\\text{subject to }x_1–x_2\le1\\3x_1–x_2\le6\\x_i\ge0$$Graphically there are multiple, unbounded solutions, but the simplex method would return unique solution if we were to conclude uniqueness due to inability to perform pivot operation.

Comment: I´ll delete my answer soon. It seems that you don´t want to understand my arguments. So sad.

Comment: I'm sorry if you are offended, this is not personal. I'm trying to understand.

Comment: No you don´t. If I´m see it right you´ve already understood all. You can leave a comment below your question if you want to leave a message for me.

Comment: I have this one question: Not being able to make a pivot operation does not necessarily mean unique solution. Is that right?

Comment: Haven´t you already accepted an answer?

Comment: Why are you deleting your answer? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: I have accepted another answer, but I have also upvoted yours.

Comment: I appreaciate your upvote. But I´m convinced that my answer fits much more your question.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri what if we dont know the original lpp. We just see the optimal table with the same situation as you have in your question. So a non basic variable wants to enter but no variable wants to leave. Does it indicate a variable with unrestricted condition, and the overall solution being unique? Or can it also indicate non-basic alternate optimum solutions which the simplex wouldnt find.